# How to use HiddenFor with an expression of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an extension that creates a component, in this component I'am adding a HiddenFor.

This is the code:

```
class Test<TModel>
{

     protected HtmlHelper<TModel> HtmlHelper { get; set; }

     public void MyFunction<TColumnModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expVal, string name, params Expression<Func<TColumnModel, object>>[] columns)
     {

          // Make some stuff with columns

          var hidden = this.HtmlHelper.HiddenFor(expVal);

     }

}
```

The problem is:

When I execute the code above, it returns the following error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

Ok, this error ocurrs because I am trying to create a HiddenFor using an expression of object, if I make a cast, it will probably resolve, but, how to make a cast of an expression without compile it? I don't want to compile the expression to get the value every time.

Another solution, could be instead of use an expression of `TModel` and `object`, use an expression of two generic types, like that:

```
MyFunction<TColumnModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expVal
```

But, when I call this method I don't know the type of `TValue`, it would not be a problem, but as I have to inform the `TColumModel` I will have to inform the `TValue` too.

So, there are two questions:

Is there a way to create a HiddenFor of an expression of object?

I can call a method with two generic types, passing just one?

Thanks